# Cursor merging values from multiple rows. PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I've got table EMP which contains employees name and department he works in. Something like say (obviously it's way bigger than my example):

```
dept name
10   Clark
10   King
20   Jacob
30   Michael
10   Miller 
30   John
40   Leonardo
```

Then there's second table:

```
Emps_in_Depts (Deptno NUMBER(2), Employees VARCHAR2(4000))
```

And my task is to write PL/SQL code which would insert data into that second table in such fashion:

```
(10,CLARK$KING$MILLER$)
(30,Michael$John)
```

and so on for every dept there is.

I have basic idea of using cursor inside cursor but I have no idea how to merge values from multiple rows into a single one.

```
  DECLARE
     CURSOR kursor
     IS
       SELECT DISTINCT deptno
       FROM emp;
     
       departament  
            emp.deptno%TYPE;
  BEGIN
     OPEN kursor;

    LOOP
       FETCH kursor INTO departament;
       EXIT WHEN kursor%NOTFOUND;
       
       --HERE SHOULD BE SECOND CURSOR 
       --which I'm not sure how to code so that it fetches from  
       --SELECT ename FROM emp WHERE deptno = departament
       --
       --and it should insert values into Emps_in_depts here I guess.
   
     END LOOP;

     CLOSE kursor;
  END;
```

Comment: This is a really bad design for the Emps_in_Depts table. Why are you storing multiple names concatenated in one column? Why not just create a view instead? You can do this w/o any PL/SQL. See example here - http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

Comment: It's task for uni :) I haven't designed it, it's just what they made me do :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is basically:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR; 
    empname   EmpCurTyp;
    nameList varchar2(4000);
    name varchar2(200);
BEGIN
    OPEN empname FOR  -- open cursor variable
        'SELECT name FROM emp WHERE dept = :s' USING departament;
    LOOP
        FETCH empname INTO name
        EXIT WHEN empname%NOTFOUND
        nameList:=nameList||'$'||name
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE empname;
    INSERT INTO emps_in_deps VALUES (departament, nameList)
END
```

Comment: No need to use PL/SQL at all. See other answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Guntram Blohm, helped me a TON. Now my task is complete :) @OldProgrammer Thanks, I know, but it was required for my university task :)

Answer (score 2):

Check function [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) (available since Oracle 11.2), you can alomost copy it from documentation.